# Synchonous finite state machine from output sequence

Tags: design, flipflop, state-machines, synchronous

I'm reviewing for my exam and this questing popped from questions that were previously asked in the exam. Problem is below.

[image: Problem]

**Question:** I'm totally confused about this, how do I get started?

**Trial:** My first intuition is that I should make 4 D flip flop sequence and put the RUN input to the enable input of the last 2 Dff's, and take the A and B from the first two. But I'm pretty sure that this isn't what is wanted here because there should be excitation function from the Dff.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your trial assumptions.  4 D or 2 D FFs for state + 2 for output.

Answer (score 0):

2 D FFs for state and 2 D FFs for output.  This is based upon your trial.

[image: FSM]